# Understanding Likelihood Function

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Just learning Bayesian techniques through Insua et.al.'s "Bayesian Analysis of Stochastic Process Models."  On page 18 they give an example of a gambler estimating the parameter $p$ in a binomial distribution after observing 9 heads in 12 coin tosses $\mathbf{x}$.  Given her prior $f(p) = Beta(5,5)$, they state the posterior is
\begin{align*}
f(p|\mathbf{x}) & \propto f(\mathbf{x}|p)f(p) \\
& \propto {12 \choose 9} p^9 (1-p)^3 \frac{1}{B(5,5)}p^{5-1}(1-p)^{5-1} \\
& \propto p^{14-1} (1-p)^{8-1}
\end{align*}
and therefore $p|\mathbf{x} \sim Beta(14,8)$.

For the same problem they plot the likelihood function, but I guess they view it as function of $p$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$, and to do so they must normalize it so it becomes a pdf for $p$.  Hence the likelihood function, which was a binomial(12,p) is now
$$
\frac{l(p|\mathbf{x})}{\int_0^1 l(p|x)dp} = \frac{1}{B(10,4)}p^{10-1}(1-p)^{4-1},
$$ 
which is a $Beta(10,4)$ pdf.  I.e., we have transformed the probability *mass* function $f(\mathbf{x}|p)$, a function of $\mathbf{x}$, into a probability *density* function $l(p|\mathbf{x})$, a function of $p$.  Is this a proper way of understanding it?

Comment: The likelihood *IS* a function of your model parameters and not the observed data. There is no reason why this function should be a valid density (i.e. integrate to 1 wrt to the parameters). Hence one must normalize it to make it a valid PDF. 
There is a subtle point here that the likelihood may not be integratable at all in some cases. So, I am not sure if the second equation can be generalised to all cases. Wait for someone with more knowledge of this than me to clarify this!

Comment: There's usually no reason to normalize a likelihood (either as a Bayesian or as a frequentist); generally one proceeds to a posterior -- and where necessary (i.e. if it is not obtained in normalized form), to normalize *that*.